# Как изменить размер div блока мышкой?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как можно изменить высоту или ширину блока с помощью мышки, без библиотеки `jquery-ui` ?

Такой как [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/qLauvqjz/3/), только без `jquery-ui`, искал в интернете, но не смог найти.

Может есть какие-то другие библиотеки (размером 5-10 kb.) но не такие большие как `jquery-ui`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если тебе нужно изменять ширину блока мышкой, вот [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/nt7uou3h/). Если немножко изменить скрипт, я думаю что и высоту можно менять, только `css` код нужно доделать.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var p = $(".pan1");
    var d = $(".pan2");
    var r = $("#resize");    
    var curr_width = p.width()
    var unlock = false;   
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
          var change = curr_width + (e.clientX - curr_width);       
       if(unlock) {
                if(change > 199) {
                    $("#debug").text(e.clientX + " resize");
                    p.css("width", change);
                    d.css("margin-left", change);
                }
                else {
                    p.css("width", 200);
                    d.css("margin-left", 200);
            }
        }
    });     
    r.mousedown(function(e) {
        curr_width = p.width();
        unlock = true;
        r.css("background-color", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)");
    });
    $(document).mousedown(function(e) {
        if(unlock) {
          e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
        unlock = false;
        $("#debug").text("");
        r.css("background-color", "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

В [продвинутых](http://caniuse.com/#search=resize) браузерах есть специальное свойство:

```
resize: none | both | horizontal | vertical
```

Думаю, описания значений свойства не требуется. Нужно добавить, что для всех элементов, кроме `textarea`, свойство работает, только если у элемента установлено свойство `overflow`, в отличное от `visible` значение.

Узнать, что это свойство есть, можно с помощью [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/download?cssresize-dontmin-setclasses&q=res), либо, просто проверить, есть ли у элемента это свойство:

```
var div = document.createElement('div')
if (typeof div.style.resize == 'undefined'){
   console.log('нет');
}
```

Если этого свойства нет, тогда уже можно использовать для этих целей JS.